# How to retrieve nested asList elements

Tags: java, arrays, nested

I'm working on a program that uses the iterator methods next() and has next() to iterate through nested arrays, and read the elements at index 0 for each nested list then 1, then 2 and so forth and put then upon completion prints a complete array of all the elements put together, however I can only return the complete lists and cannot access the individual index elements of the lists

I've attempted for loops, get() and converting to array to use that indexing but to no avail

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<List<Integer>> iterators = asList (
             asList (1, 2, 3),
             asList(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
             asList(10, 11 ,12));
      // System.out.println();
        Iterator Flattenediterator = iterators.iterator();
        while (Flattenediterator.hasNext())
        //    for (int i = 0, )
        {
            System.out.println(Flattenediterator.next());
        }

    }
```

this is a new concept to me, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: *FYI:* Naming local variable `iterators` is misleading, since it doesn't have any iterators. Perhaps naming it `lists` would be better, don't you think?

Comment: I agree, but the website I got the practice exercise from specified that's what it should be called for when I run test cases

Comment: Assign the value of `Flattenediterator.next()` to a variable. What is the type of that variable? Right, as `List<Integer>`. Now get value at index 0. When `while` loop ends, do it again but for index 1. Then again for index 2. Repeat until you reach the end of all lists.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much! that solved my issue :)